# RTSP stream opens but cannot use VideoWriter on it

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp

I'm running `rtsp-simple-server`, I'm trying to feed my camera feed to the rtsp stream but the `VideoWriter` is returning not opened. Anything I'm doing wrong?

I created a small sample, Recreating the problem.

```py
import cv2

# camera index
camera_index = 0

# RTSP address
rtsp_address = "rtsp://localhost:8554/stream1"

# create a video capture object
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_index)

# check if the capture object was successfully created
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Failed to open camera")
    exit()

# create a video writer object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"H264")
try :
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(rtsp_address, fourcc, 20.0,(int(cap.get(3)),int(cap.get(4))))
except Exception as ex :
    print(ex)

# check if the video writer object was successfully created
if not out.isOpened():
    print("Failed to open RTSP stream")
    exit()

# loop through frames
while True:
    # capture a frame from the camera
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # check if the frame was successfully captured
    if not ret:
        print("Failed to capture frame")
        break

    # write the frame to the video writer object
    out.write(frame)

    # display the frame (optional)
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

    # wait for key press to exit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

# release resources
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```